# (calc) How would I find the initial function's graph from the graph of the derivative?

Tags: calculus

[Graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGnMF.png)

(The graph at the top is derivitive and the multiple choice answers are graphs of the initial function)

I know it can either be only A or C - they are almost identical, except on C, the x interval 2 through 4 has been moved down, creating holes at x=2 and 4.

Since our derivative has holes at 2 and 4, wouldn't the answer be C.

If not, how would the derivative at A have holes at 2 and 4 if it is a constant parabola?

Comment: It is correct that the _derivative_ of $f'$ has holes. That's not the same thing as "$f'$ has holes."

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the graph A. Why?

Let's see why B or C cannot be.

C) because $f$ is discontinuous at $x=2$ and $x=4$ then it would not be differentiable at these two points and the graph of $f'$ would have holes(or jump discontinuity).

B) from the graph of $f', f'(x) \ge 0$ at $x \in (1,5)$ so $f$ is increcreasing at that interval which we can clearly see that $f$ from B) is not

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So how does the function in graph A have a derivative that is not continuous, yet differentiable at x=2 and 4? I'm just slightly confused by the bend that is there at these points.

Comment: The edges in the graph of $f'$ (the bends at $x=2$ and $ x=4$) do not mean that it is not continuous. These edges imply that it is not differentiable at these points($f''$ is not differentiable at these points). Another example you can look is $f(x)=|x|$. If you make the graph of $f$ you can see an edge at $x=0$. It is continuous (by definition if we take the side limits) but it is not differentiable at $x=0$. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yea, I got those mixed up, but I do understand how it is continuous, yet not differential. Why is it that the derivative at a point of discontinuity cannot be continuous?